# Как локализовать приложение в Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

Господа разработчики!!

У кого есть уже приложения/игры на Google Play. Вопрос к вам, но может кто-то еще знает - как добавить перевод контента приложения в Google Play Console. Имеется в виду не описание приложения, а именно перевод того что есть внутри приложения. Пока что я нашел только страницу с заказом переводов и все, но вся суть в том что переводы у меня уже есть и нужно их куда-то выгрузить.

Вообще странная система - куча инструкций, куча текста как и что делать, а куда написать в поддержку нигде нету))

Comment: о каком контенте речь?

Comment: @Эникейщик, строки в приложении, все что в приложении есть в ресах которые переведены, вот я хочу strings.xml например русской локали бросить куда-то, только не понял пока куда

Comment: Еще больше запутался. Локализация приложения лежит в values-XX в проекте. values-ru в данном случае. Google Play тут вообще не относится. Или я неправильно понял?

Comment: почти правильно, смотрите у меня на пк есть проект, если я его запускаю на эмуляторе то все гуд, 4 языка есть, и весь контент (строки) переведены нормально, выгружаю в консоль, и там только дефолтный язык и все, вопрос - как сделать мултиязычное приложение не только у меня на пк, но и у гугла, так может понятнее будет?)

Comment: а как вы определяете, какие там есть языки?

Comment: там это в плей консоле? все просто - качаю приложение, и пробую изменить языки, в итоге мой механизм не работает вообще и ничего не меняется, поэтому я допустил что есть какая-то проблема, так как есть только один перевод на дефолтный язык

Comment: измените язык системы на телефоне, тогда и  в приложении поменяется.

Comment: да, так можно будет конечно наверное поменять язык в приложении, но суть в том что у меня можно менять языки независимо от языка системы, и тут я пытаюсь понять - мой механизм не работает, или просто нету ресов)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, чтобы проверить есть ли у вас переводе в приложении, скачанном из маркета - декомпилируйте файл приложения и посмотрите. Их может там действительно не быть, если вы неосторожно согласились выкладывать `App Bundle` вместо `APK`. В таком случае - да, переключение языка в рантайме может не работать. Как это чинить - лично у меня нет идей. По идее, через консоль это не исправить. Точно сработает отказ от ресурсов вообще и написание собственной их реализации. Ну или выкладывание приложения в виде APK файла. Но старое придётся бросить - обновить нельзя.

Comment: С техподдержкой гугла не связаться - вам ответит робот и будет хорошо, если не забанит за обращение)

Comment: Вроде бы нашёл [костыль](https://github.com/zeugma-solutions/locale-helper-android). Попробуйте вот это в скрипт сборки добавить - должно, вроде, запрещать убирать переводы из `app bundle`: `android {
    //...
    //... removed for brevity
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Это не то чтобы лучшее, скорее самое простое решение... Да и работать это будет только если приложение вы ещё не выкладывали. Вроде бы нельзя поменять AppBundle на APK. Скорее всего в будущем APK вообще запретят выкладывать. Из побочных эффектов - больший размер приложения для юзеров, недовольство гугла и, как следствие, скорее всего, понижение ранжирования приложения среди аналогов в маркете. С другой стороны, AppBundle, вроде, нельзя самостоятельно подписывать, а значит с APK у вас больше контроля над продуктом.