# Смена языка внутри приложения перестала работать на новейших телефонах/операционках (set new locale)

Tags: android-studio, locale, локализация, смена-языка

Два года работало всё без проблем.
Сейчас меняет языки только на отладочном телефоне (Xiaomi Redmi Note 7, Андроид 9, MIUI 10), подключенным к Андроид Студио (компьютеру), а при установке из Google Play Маркета не хочет изменять язык (ранее изменяло)

Вот два традиционных варианта кода (описанных на многих форумах). Нынче оба отказались работать нормально! :) Т.е. при установке с Play Маркета (на новейшие телефоны, начиная с Андроид 9) начались проблемы!

Первый вариант:

```
Locale LOCALE = new Locale("es");  
Locale.setDefault(LOCALE);
Configuration configuration=new Configuration(); 
configuration.locale = LOCALE;
getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration,null);
```

Второй вариант:

```
Locale LOCALE = new Locale("es");  
Locale.setDefault(LOCALE);
Configuration configuration=getResources().getConfiguration(); 
configuration.locale = LOCALE;
getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

P.S. Речь идет о любом языке, не только об испанском. Т.е. ни на какой другой язык смена текущего языка не происходит из приложений установленных с Play Маркета (ранее проиходило). Среда разработки Андроид Студио никаких подсказок не дает!

Comment: а раньше она работала (смена локали имеется в виду) при установке с плей маркета?

Comment: @Andrew Goroshko Да конечно

Comment: у меня тоже такая проблема возникла, хотя я только недавно (недели две) выложил приложение и только в тестирование, вероятнее всего будет поддержка мультиязычности с привязкой к локали телефона, самому поменять язык я не знаю как в приложении при скачивании из маркета, хотя я такой механизм делал))

Comment: В сторе Apk или App bundle?

Comment: @Эникейщик App bundle

Comment: App bundle насколько я знаю нет такой возможности, я с таким тоже столкнулся :(

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1035265/238742